# How changes in nationality affects indefinite leave to remain

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship, residency, pakistani-citizen

I hold Pakistani passport and hold Indefinite Leave to Remain in the UK. Recently I have been offered Bahraini nationality (my country of birth) which would mean I will have to give up my Pakistani nationality as you cannot hold dual nationality with Bahraini passport.

My question is if I get Bahraini passport, how would it affect my Indefinite Leave to Remain in the UK.

Comment: It may depends under which circumstances you obtained with ILR. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Your IRL would very likely be affected by a change of nationality however I would advise to contact your [citizen advice bureau](http://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/) for free legal advice if your are still in the UK or the nearest British embassy/consulate for clarifications.

Comment: As long as he keeps his passports as a record, it will have zero effect.

Answer (score 0):

It will not affect your ILR at all. As long as you keep all of your passports together and keep a good record of all your details, ILR is strictly an arrangement between you and the UK and is not in anyway reliant upon your citizenship status (as long as you don't become British, in which case your ILR status ends).